# Remove lines with a specific char with javascript and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text files containing something as:

```
CID Principal CID 2 CID 3 CID 4
-
-
-
-
Observações Gerais:
Paciente relata dor cronica ,agudizada e limitante do joelho direito , edema +/3+, nega trauma ou queda, dor a palpação na interlinha articular medial.
Hipótese Diagnóstica:
Conduta:
Lisador dip, restiva 5 mg adesivos, gelo, fisioterapia, Rx da bacia, joelhos com carga e orientações.
```

I´d like a regex to get rid of:

- all empty lines
- lines containing only "-" and no more chars.

I have tried:

```
mytext.replace(/^\s*[\r\n\-]/gm, "");
```

But no luck.
How could I do that using javascript?

Comment: The regex is matching the `-` lines? https://regex101.com/r/HcCxd5/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the lines with hyphens always consist of a single hyphen, you might as well go with a non-regex solution like

```js
text.split("\n").filter(x => x.trim().length > 0 && x != '-').join("\n")
```

As for a regex solution, you can use

```js
/^(?:\s*|-+)$[\r\n]*/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1eOYIT/2). Note it will remove lines that consist of one or more hyphens, if this is not expected replace `-+` with `-`.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `(?:\s*|-+)` - either zero or more whitespaces or one or more hyphens
- `$` - end of line
- `[\r\n]*` - zero or more CR or LF chars.

See a JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "CID Principal CID 2 CID 3 CID 4\n-\n-\n-\n-\nObservações Gerais:\nPaciente relata dor cronica ,agudizada e limitante do joelho direito , edema +/3+, nega trauma ou queda, dor a palpação na interlinha articular medial.\nHipótese Diagnóstica:\nConduta:\nLisador dip, restiva 5 mg adesivos, gelo, fisioterapia, Rx da bacia, joelhos com carga e orientações.";
const regex = /^(?:\s*|-+)$[\r\n]*/gm;
console.log(text.replace(regex, ''));
// Non-regex solution:
console.log(text.split("\n").filter(x => x.trim().length > 0 && x != '-').join("\n"));
```

Comment: Thank you. It works well. Now I am getting with other text strings something as: 'Anamnese\n' +
    '========\n' +
    '\n' +
    'CID Principal CID 2 CID 3 CID 4 \n' +
    'Observações Gerais: \n' +
    'retornando querendo acupuntura dado pedido parou a terapia cd: acupuntura + orientada a retornar para terapia \n' +
    'Hipótese Diagnóstica: \n' +
    'Conduta: \n'   . Is possible get rid off that '\n'?

Comment: @LuizAlves Ok, I see, the `\s+` must be replaced with `\s*`.